# How to dump every Flickr photo url from a set?

Tags: javascript, url, anchor, batch-processing, flickr

I'm not sure if this question is possible but what I want is to take a set of photos from Flickr and dump every url into a file (text is fine). Dumping them within anchor tags would be plus. So far I've seen [this](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html) and I looked through the Galleria viewers JavaScript code but no luck. I'm expecting a simple few lines of code to do this because Galleria does it but I'm not really sure where in their code Flickr is accessed to get the image urls.

Comment: You can start by applying for an [API key](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html). Per *"To use the Flickr API you need to have an application key. We use this to track API usage."*

Comment: I think I found it and I wouldn't need that key, see my answer.

Comment: Actually it does need the key but the answer doesn't seem to run.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the answer actually but if someone else comes along and has another answer I'll of course accept theirs instead of just mine.

It seems that [phpflickr](http://phpflickr.com/examples/a-users-photos/source/) has this example which should work:

```
<?php
require_once("phpFlickr/phpFlickr.php");
// Create new phpFlickr object
$f = new phpFlickr("[API Key]");
$f->enableCache(
    "db",
    "mysql://[username]:[password]@[server]/[database]"
);

$i = 0;
if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    // Find the NSID of the username inputted via the form
    $person = $f->people_findByUsername($_POST['username']);

    // Get the friendly URL of the user's photos
    $photos_url = $f->urls_getUserPhotos($person['id']);

    // Get the user's first 36 public photos
    $photos = $f->people_getPublicPhotos($person['id'], NULL, NULL, 36);

    // Loop through the photos and output the html
    foreach ((array)$photos['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
        echo "<a href=$photos_url$photo[id]>";
        echo "<img border='0' alt='$photo[title]' ".
            "src=" . $f->buildPhotoURL($photo, "Square") . ">";
        echo "</a>";
        $i++;
        // If it reaches the sixth photo, insert a line break
        if ($i % 6 == 0) {
            echo "<br>\n";
        }
    }
}
?>

<h3>Enter a username to search for</h3>
<form method='post'>
    <input name='username'><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Display Photos'>
</form>

<p><a href="source">View Source</a></p>
```